# NSubstitute: How to unit test LoggerMessageAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, nsubstitute

Previously I was logging with LogWarning and had tests like this:

```cs
var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();
// Do stuff...
logger.Received(1).Log(LogLevel.Warning, 0, Arg.Any<AnyType>(), null, Arg.Any<Func<AnyType, Exception?, string>>());
```

But since `EventLogLogger` is [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.eventlog.eventloglogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0). I should use [LoggerMessageAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logger-message-generator).

How can I test, that logger was logging?

Comment: What is your actual code that you're writing test for it?